# Silent Rewrite Rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make this redirection:

www.domain.com/es/j/j1.html => www.domain.com/j/j1.html?lang=es

To do this I have created an .htacces in the folder /es/j with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^j(.*)$ www.domain.com/j/j$1?lang=es
```

It works, but the thing is that I need to do it "silently", I mean, the url in the browser must show www.domain.com/es/j/j1.html instead of www.domain.com/j/j1.html?lang=es

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a silent rewrite then use this code.

In **root .htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^es/(j/.+?\.html)$ /$1?lang=es [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work. Should I change "QUERY_STRING" by something?

Comment: The input url is www.domain.com/es/j/j1.html but it remains unchanged. (note that I have the htaccess file in the folder /es/j/ should I change its location?)

Comment: Again i'm sorry but it doesn't work (page not found 404). Note that I don't want to redirect "es/j/j1.html" to "es/j/j1.html?lang=es" but to "j/j1.html?lang=es" (i.e. out of the folder "es")

Comment: I put the htaccess in the folder /es/j but i can put it anywhere else. There are no more rules in this file

Comment: It works. But when the user enters the url www.domain.com/es/j/j1.html I want the browser display the url, but internally (silently) redirect to www.domain.com/j/j1.html?lang=es

Comment: It doesn't work either, but thank you for your ideas, I finally found the solution!

Comment: Good that it worked and please don't post another answer based on this answer. I have invested so much time to help you. If you wanted a .htaccess in root that could be done similar way. (See updated answer)

Comment: ok, change your answer by the one I posted, and I will mark it as the accepted one. thanks again

Comment: Can you remove the first alternative? it doesn't work for me. Only the htaccess in the root makes the job. Thanks!